# How to convert a UTF-8 file to UTF-16 format in Java?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, utf-16

I have got a file with text in it, which is in UTF-8 format. I want to convert the content of that file to UTF-16 file format, but I want to keep the special characters. How can I do this?

My attempt:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

// ...
// read content from file
// ...

writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_16));

// ...
// write content to file
// ...
```

However the special characters are lost using this approach. "ÜÖÄ²³§`´" resulted in "ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½`ï¿½". I also tried replacing the characters in the Java string, but the read character is already malformed at this point. How can this be done?

Comment: How did you "// read content from file" and "// write content to file"?

Comment: (Note that `ï¿½` is UTF-8 for �)

Comment: And how are you looking at the file characters? Are you sure the text editor used to inspect the file content uses the right encoding?

Comment: Side comment: you could simply `Files.write(path, Files.readAllLines(path, UTF_8), UTF_16);`

Comment: @JoshLee Or, more accurately, "ï¿½" is [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) for "�" when written using UTF-8 and read, not with UTF-8, but with ISO 8859-1, Windows-1252, Windows-1254, Windows-1258 or ISO 8859-9. But I think you pointing it out helps show that it's the code that's not shown that's the problem.